# Can multiple select () is allowed in a single tcp client server program

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

I am developing client server program in windows platform using c++ which is as follows.

1.I have remote data center(server).
                 2. I have one gateway(client)  which will connect with the data center(tcp).
3. I have a gui application which manages the gateway remotely.

So here for GUI Gateway is Server.

I did the following things

**I have two listener thread in gateway where in each thread select() system call is called.**

1. Data center Listener Thread- this will entertain the data from the Data center.
2. GUI listener thread  - this will entertain the data from the GUI.

when i start the gateway two listener automatically starts and listen for the connection and data from both data center and GUI.

Gateway connected with the data center and receives the data as well. BUt when i start the gui application and tries to connect the connect returns 0 but it doesnot call accept in the GUI  listener thread in gateway.

1. Is this problem due to two select system call in the application?
2. if it is so what is the reasin for this.?

   ```
   void* CConnectionMgr::ListnerThreadDataCenter(void* args)
   {
    CGatewayInstanceManager* pGatewayInstance = (CGatewayInstanceManager*)args;

   fd_set fdRead;
   fd_set fdExcept;

   int nSelectRetVal = 0;

   timeval tv;
   tv.tv_sec = 2;
   tv.tv_usec = 0; 

   while(true)
   {
   FD_ZERO(&fdRead);       
   FD_ZERO(&fdExcept);
   GatewayConnection::iterator itrGatewayCon;
   GatewayConnection mapGatewayConn = pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetGatewayConnection();
   itrGatewayCon = mapGatewayConn.begin();

   while (itrGatewayCon != mapGatewayConn.end())
   {
       FD_SET (itrGatewayCon->second,&fdRead);     
       FD_SET (itrGatewayCon->second,&fdExcept);
       itrGatewayCon++;
   }
   nSelectRetVal =  select(NULL,&fdRead,NULL,&fdExcept,&tv);

   // demultiplexing the socket for in coming message
   if (nSelectRetVal>0)
   {
       for ( itrGatewayCon = mapGatewayConn.begin();itrGatewayCon!= mapGatewayConn.end();itrGatewayCon++)
       {
               //Reading packet from the socket
               unsigned char* pPacket = pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->ReadPacketDataFromSocket(itrGatewayCon->second);
               CProtocolMgr objProtocol;
               CMessage* pMessage = objProtocol.ParseMsg(pPacket);
               pGatewayInstance->HandleRequest(pMessage);
       }

   }
   DWORD dwWaitResult;      
   dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(ghListenerThreadDataCenterShutdownEvent,WAIT_TIME);
   if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwWaitResult)  
       break;      
   }

   return 0;
      }



   void* CConnectionMgr::ListnerThreadUI(void* args)
   {
   CGatewayInstanceManager* pGatewayInstance = (CGatewayInstanceManager*)args;
   fd_set fdRead;
   fd_set fdExcept;

   int nSelectRetVal = 0;

   timeval tv;
   tv.tv_sec = 2;
   tv.tv_usec = 0; 
   while(true)
   {
   FD_ZERO(&fdRead);       
   FD_ZERO(&fdExcept);
   if (pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetServerSocket()!=-1 )
   {
       FD_SET (pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetServerSocket(),&fdRead);       
       FD_SET (pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetServerSocket(),&fdExcept);
   }

   UIConnection::iterator itrUIConnection;
   UIConnection listUIConnection = pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetUIConnection();        
   for(itrUIConnection = listUIConnection.begin();itrUIConnection != listUIConnection.end();itrUIConnection++)
   {           
       if ( *itrUIConnection != -1)
       {
           FD_SET (*itrUIConnection,&fdRead);      
           FD_SET (*itrUIConnection,&fdExcept);
       }
   }
   // demultiplexing the socket for in coming message
   nSelectRetVal =  select(NULL,&fdRead,NULL,&fdExcept,&tv);       
   if(nSelectRetVal>0)
   {           
       if (FD_ISSET(pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetServerSocket(),&fdRead))
       {
           // accepting and new client and updating the UIConnection List
           int nAcceptRetVal = 0;              
           nAcceptRetVal = pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->ManageConnection(pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr());
           continue;               
       }
       if (FD_ISSET(pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->GetServerSocket(),&fdExcept))
       {

       }           
       for( itrUIConnection = listUIConnection.begin();itrUIConnection != listUIConnection.end();itrUIConnection++)
       {
           if (FD_ISSET(*itrUIConnection,&fdRead))
           {
               //Reading packet from the socket
               //string strPacket = pGatewayInstance->GetConnectionMgr()->ReadPacketDataFromSocket(*itrUIConnection);
               //pGatewayInstance->HandleRequest();
           }               
       }
   }
   DWORD dwWaitResult;      
   dwWaitResult =    WaitForSingleObject(ghListenerThreadUIShutDownEvent,WAIT_TIME);
   if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwWaitResult)  
       break;      
       }
       return 0;
       }
   int CConnectionMgr::ManageConnection(CConnectionMgr* pConMgr)
   {
      sockaddr_in addrConnectedPeer;
      int nAddrLen =sizeof(addrConnectedPeer) ;
      int nAcceptRetVal = accept(pConMgr->GetServerSocket(),(sockaddr*)&addrConnectedPeer,&nAddrLen);  
      if (nAcceptRetVal>0)
      {
      pConMgr->AddUIConnection(nAcceptRetVal);     
      }
       return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

did you check the manual for your select implementation? Because select usually expectes the first param to be the highest fd +1.
See here: http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/select/

basically, select can be used more than once in an app, but the fd-masks (param 2,3,4) should be different - otherwise processing of input will be duplicated.

**EDIT:**

A return value of 0 indicates a timeout, no activity on any of the specified fds.

hth Mario

Comment: A retval of 0 means no socket is ready, nothing happend on any socket timeout perhapse?

Comment: Return of 0 means connection successful http://black.goucher.edu/~kelliher/cs43/mar19.html

Comment: ah, sorry! I misread your post! 0 return on select means no activity! When the connect is successfull at the client, what happens at the server? does the select return?

Comment: to clarify my answer: I do believe that the same fd can only be used in one select. If an FD is used in two selects, only one is triggered. This is an assumption, but I beleive this confirms it: http://books.google.at/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA831&lpg=PA831&dq=select+same+fd&source=bl&ots=Kr0BPickOu&sig=R6qTVoeQoauMhLgEl0LaPVl89Wg&hl=de&ei=Xue_TZ74BsvBswb0sYzDBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=select%20same%20fd&f=false

Comment: Thanks Mario for your reply the problem got resolved.system deos allow more than one select system call.the problem was due to wrong sockaddr .